# Obtain input and append into separate list

Tags: python

I have a set of integers that will be an input for my set of code and after the input, i want to append them into separate list. My input has ':' that acts as a separator.

Example of user input:

```
10.3:42.1:54.7:65.2
```

Example of output:

```
List1 = [10.3,42.1]
List2 = [54.7,65.2]
```

My code:

```
userInput = input("Enter input digits)
#It's not possible for float only as it also has ':'?
List1 = []
List2 = []

for i in userInput:
    List1.append()
    List2.append()
    .
    .
```

I'm not familiar with inputs with both floats and punctuations in them. I'll appreciate if anyone could explain on how i could implement them correctly as an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, ":" is used as separator, so you can split the input string when ":" occurs and then convert to floats.

Is there any particular logic how you create two separate output lists?

```
input_str = "10.3:42.1:54.7:65.2"

string_separated = input_str.split(":")
# Strings -> ['10.3', '42.1', '54.7', '65.2']

all_floats = [float(el) for el in string_separated]
# Floats -> [10.3, 42.1, 54.7, 65.2]

# Divide output in two lists
List1, List2 = all_floats[:2], all_floats[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete code you need:

```
userInput = input("Enter input digits")
numbers = [float(x) for x in userInput.split(':')]
List1 = numbers[0:2]
List2 = numbers[2:4]
```